# Getting the first and last day of a month in ruby from partial string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table with a column for `year`, which is an `integer`, and a column for `month`, which again is an `integer`. I need (in ruby) to be able to end up with a `start_date` and an `end_date` for each row.

So from the first row, where the year is 2016 and the month is 1, I need to get start_date = 01/01/2016 and end date = 31/01/2016. i know I can get them in ruby with beginning_of_month and end_of_month, but I need to get to a date first?

I'm getting lost in Date.parse and Date.strptime, and could really do with someone explaining it. Presumably I cannot get a date to begin with because I don't actually have a day to work with !

help :)

Comment: In future you may wish to consider waiting longer before selecting an answer. Quick selections may short-circuit those still working on answers and discourage other answers. There's no rush. It seems to me that [Date::new](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-new) is clearly the way to go here, as it avoids the need to construct an intermediate string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you know the month and year already you have solved half of your problem already because each month begins with the 1st.

You can use that to build an initial date and then you can call `end_of_month` to do the heavy lifting for you.

```
month = 4
year = 2016    
beginning_of_month = "#{year}-#{month}-01".to_date
end_of_month = beginning_of_month.end_of_month
```

Comment: Haha, posted my answer 7 seconds after yours and almost identical solution :)

Comment: Perfect, can't believe I couldn't get my head there !

Answer (score 4):

You can simply parse the date as if it were the 1st day of the month:

```
 year = 2016
 month = 6
 d = Date.parse("#{year}-#{month}-01")
 # => Wed, 01 Jun 2016
```

And then calculate the last day using `end_of_month` method, just as you proposed:

```
 d.end_of_month
 # => Thu, 30 Jun 2016
```

Comment: There's no need to construct a string and then `parse` it when you can simply plug `year` and `month` into [Date::new](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-new).

Comment: Correct! I like the @steenslag's solution the best in the end, too.

Answer (score 3):

```
require "date"
year_months = [[2016, 5], [2015, 6]]

dates = year_months.map do |y, m|
  [Date.new(y, m, 1), Date.new(y, m, -1)] # -1 is last day of month
end
```

Comment: Just a note that `Date.new(y, m, 1)` can be replaced by `Date.new(y, m)`, but the former is arguably clearer. Also, this solution does not require Rails (is pure Ruby).